# Output specific facts by increasing order of a certain value in CLIPS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system

I have the following list of facts :

```
f-0    (initial-fact)
f-1    (fact 1 [input_1] 21)
f-2    (fact 1 [input_2] 28)
f-3    (fact 1 [input_3] 10)
f-4    (fact 1 [input_4] 25)
f-5    (fact 1 Normal Operation!)
f-6    (fact 2 [input_1] 7)
f-7    (fact 2 [input_2] 25)
f-8    (fact 2 [input_3] 13)
f-9    (fact 2 [input_4] 15)
f-10   (fact 2 adder a1 error!)
f-11   (fact 3 [input_1] 11)
f-12   (fact 3 [input_2] 17)
f-13   (fact 3 [input_3] 24)
f-14   (fact 3 [input_4] 31)
f-15   (fact 3 multiplier p1 error!)
```

Is there a way to somehow choose and print from all these facts the ones that contain only the number and the type of error? For example I want to print in increasing order:

```
1 Normal Operation!
2 adder a1 error!
3 multiplier p1 error!
```

Note that I actually have more facts and the order that they are in the fact list is not in increasing order as I have shown. So I have to somehow make it increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(deffacts initial
   (fact 1 [input_1] 21)
   (fact 1 [input_2] 28)
   (fact 1 [input_3] 10)
   (fact 1 [input_4] 25)
   (fact 1 Normal Operation!)
   (fact 2 [input_1] 7)
   (fact 2 [input_2] 25)
   (fact 2 [input_3] 13)
   (fact 2 [input_4] 15)
   (fact 2 adder a1 error!)
   (fact 3 [input_1] 11)
   (fact 3 [input_2] 17)
   (fact 3 [input_3] 24)
   (fact 3 [input_4] 31)
   (fact 3 multiplier p1 error!))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction compare-1st (?f1 ?f2)
   (> (nth$ 1 (fact-slot-value ?f1 implied))
      (nth$ 1 (fact-slot-value ?f2 implied))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule print
   =>
   (bind ?facts 
      (find-all-facts ((?f fact)) 
                      (not (instance-namep (nth$ 2 ?f:implied)))))
   (bind ?facts (sort compare-1st ?facts))
   (foreach ?f ?facts
      (bind ?data (fact-slot-value ?f implied))
      (printout t (implode$ (first$ ?data)) " " 
                  (implode$ (rest$ ?data)) crlf))) 
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
1 Normal Operation!
2 adder a1 error!
3 multiplier p1 error!
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks so much mr Gary! I am using ClipsEditor and it says there is a problem in this line : (find-all-facts ((?f fact)). However when I run it, it works. Do you know what is at fault here? Also could you explain to me a litle bit how defrule print works?

Comment: CLIPSEditor probably doesn't understand the syntax of the find-all-facts command. The print rule uses the find-all-facts function to retrieve all the facts that don't contain an instance-name in the second position of the fact. It uses the sort function to sort the facts based on the first position. The foreach function then iterates over the sorted facts printing the data contained within.